# nifi cannot connect to SQLServerExpress

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, apache-nifi

I am trying to connect to SQLSERVEREXPRESS 2017 from nifi.

I have created a DBCP connection pool with the below parameters.

[DBCP Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QviSc.png)

However, i keep getting the below error when i run a ExecuteSQL processor.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMCaj.png)

Any help to correct this error will be of utmost use.

I am running

- Windows 10
- Java 8.0.1510.12
- sqljdbc42.jar
- SQL Server 2017 is on Windows Server 2012.

Thanks,
Aadil

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `Integrated Security` you must supply `user` and `password` in your connection string.